# creating a private Ethereum Token ( Coin )

Tags: ethereum, ether

I am new to ethereum, Is it possible to create a coin / token on it that is just a private token? or at least I don;t want to publicly announce its creation but send back and forth coins between 2-3 wallets only?

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to send back and forth coins between several "private" wallets, why not making your own private block chain?

You can find a lot of tutorial on the net on how to. This one (relying on Ethereum) seems to cover the topic wholly: [Here's how i built a private blockchain network and you can too](https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0)